# Removing Yahoo's blue dotted links from emails

Tags: css, html-email

Yahoo keeps inserting blue dotted links within our HTML emails on plain text within a `<p>` tag. It seems to be doing this to locations mostly.

I've tried to override this using inline styles like:

```
   style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration:none; outline: none; -moz-outline-style: none;"
```

I've done a bit of research on this and it seems like it may not be possible to remove them, but I'm just looking to confirm that.

Comment: @valentinas, what relevance is your suggestion?... he can't force _all the recipients_ of his email messages to use gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the following to the CSS before `</head>`:

```
.yshortcuts {border-bottom: none !important; color: #000000 !important}
```

There is a little bit more info on this over at [Exact Target's blog](http://blog.exacttarget.com/blog/email-design-9/design-tip-of-the-week-why-does-yahoo-put-additional-links-in-my-email).

Comment: Yup I had tried that as an inline style on a <p> tag and as a class on the container <td> with no luck.

Comment: Are you committed to using `<p>`s? I think that has worked for me in the past, but then I don't use `<p>`s in HTML email.

Comment: No, I just tried to wrap affected text in a `<span>` and with this `class .yshortcuts {border-bottom: none !important; color: #000000 !important}` but it didn't remove the link.